# bash script output not written to file in folder

Tags: bash, cron, logs

My goal is to run a script in `crontab` and save its output (via `echo` commands) to a log file. Thus, I am using the following:

```
$HOME/folder/sh/script.sh 1>$HOME/folder/logs/script.log 2>$HOME/folder/logs/script.err
```

However, from the command line (not `cron` yet), I cannot see the log file at all. The permissions are valid.

If I remove the redirections or keep the redirection to a file in the current directory, I can see the (correct) log contents.

Why doesn't `bash` script output appear in the log file under a nested folder structure?

Comment: Are all the components of the pathnames correctly spelled? Does the directory exist? Do you have write permission in the directory? Are you looking in the correct location when you look for the log files?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, yes. :D

Comment: If the shell _failed_ to create the files, it ought to give you an error. You haven't mentioned any diagnostic output from the shell or script, so we must assume that the output was actually successfully written somewhere. A directory listing of the `$HOME/folder/logs` directory would be nice to see.

Comment: That's the issue. I can't see any errors anywhere with regards to writing of the files. The `$HOME/folder/logs` is empty. BTW, here is the other things. The script has a `sudo -u dbuser -d db psql ... ` with output (`stdout` and `stderr`) redirected to different log file under the same folder structure. These log files are visible! Not the log file that should have had other `echo` outputs.

Comment: Even an empty command, redirected to a file (e.g. `: >file`, a no-op command, redirected to `file`), will create the file (the shell creates the file before executing the command).  You say that the files do not appear. This makes me believe that the redirection fails even before the script is executed.  Either that, or your script is explicitly _removing_ those files during the course of its execution.

Comment: From within the script, I did a `touch` for the log files. This creates the files, but nothing is written to it. The first line in the script is an `echo 'Script started' `date``. This isn't visible.

Comment: For the script to start at all, the files redirected into _must_ be created (see previous comment). Are you sure nothing deletes the log files during the course of running the script?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about PATH, and permissions,  and the same redirection works for other commands, it looks like your script is manipulating the log files or folders that you are trying to write (Ambiguous redirect).

It is that the case?

If so remove any lines of the script manipulating anything related to the logs, and try again.

If that works please select this as the correct answer.

If not please remove 2> run the script again, and watch what happen, maybe you will see a message showing why the script can't write to the files.

Good Lucky!